# How to add an animated cursor to a gaze input timed cursor in Unity for Google Cardboard

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I have implemented a timed gaze input in Unity for a Google Cardboard App project. I can´t figure out how to add an animated loading cursor that loads in the 2 second delay I have implemented. Here is an example of this cursor:

[image: Timed cursor]